# highway metric topologically equivalent to euclidean metric?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Consider the Euclidean metric space $(S, d_1)$ on $\mathbb{R^2}$ and the highway metric space $(S, d_h)$ on $\mathbb{R^2}$, where the highway metric is defined as 
>   $$d_h(x,y) = \begin{cases} |x_2 - y_2|, & \text{if $x_1 = y_1$} \\ |x_2| + 
> |x_1 - y_1| + |y_2|, & \text{if $x_1 \ne y_1$ }\end{cases}$$ I want to show that a nonempty subset of S is contained in a euclidean metric open ball if and only if it is contained in a highway metric open ball.

This sounds like I need to show that the two metric topologies are equivalent, so I started by showing that the highway metric topology is finer than the euclidean metric topology by bounding the highway metric below by a constant multiple of the euclidean metric, for constant k = 1.
The first case was fine since if $x_1 = y_1$, $|x_2 - y_2|^2 = (x_1 - y_1)^2 + (x_2 - y_2)^2 = 0 + (x_2 - y_2)^2 \implies  \sqrt {(x_2 - y_2)^2} \le |x_2 - y_2|$. However, in the second case, $x_1 \ne y_1$, I tried something similar, but it doesn't quite work: I tried comparing $$ |x_2|^2 + |x_1 - y_1|^2 + |y_2|^2 $$ and $$ (x_1 - y_1)^2 + (x_2 - y_2)^2 = x_2^2 + (x_1 - y_1)^2 +   y_2^2 -2xy$$ but the extra -2xy is throwing me off since if x and y have different signs, the euclidean metric is bigger, but otherwise the euclidean metric is smaller.

Comment: The topologies are **not** equivalent: the open ball of radius $1$ about $\langle 0,1\rangle$ in the $d_h$ metric is not open in the Euclidean metric. What you need to show is precisely that the highway metric topology is finer than the Euclidean topology. I would just show that every Euclidean open ball is a union of highway open sets.

Comment: @Brian since they're not topologically equivalent, doesn't that mean that there are sets contained in a highway metric ball that are not necessarily in a euclidean metric ball?